# Why was this answer deleted, and how can I avoid it in the future?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, moderators

I got my answer deleted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40592271/285587), with a moderator commenting

> This isn't codereview.stackexchange.com and your answer is not an answer, it's a critique

My answer *is* an answer, precisely explaining the reason for the error the OP is getting. The question just seems like a request for code review, but it isn't. There is a certain error. Yes, the error is caused by the wrong design, and has to be fixed by fixing the design, but the question is not about design. Nor is the answer a code review.

I suppose the following course of things:

- some unsuspecting user, being lured by the *seeming* similarity of errors, decided [to close the question as a dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40592271/revisions). But the linked question has nothing to do with either the question asked or the particular error message thrown.
- so I reopened it, intending to explain the real cause for the error, which is the wrong architectural decision.
- someone reported the matter to the mod.
- the mod decided to delete the answer and close the question.

So the question is, how can such things happen and how can we prevent them in the future?

Comment: This reads like a rant. If thats not your intention, you might want to phrase this less agressively.

Comment: Well, you made it look like a critique. "awful", "spoils the code", "wrong architectural decision" (that one is here). You make "A function should never return an error instead of a value" seem like advice on not being awful, and not spoiling code, rather than anything else.

Comment: @Pekka웃 1. code review is off topic. 2. **the answer is not a frigging code review**, it's just a precise explanation for the source of error the OP is getting.

Comment: *"it's just a precise explanation for the source of error the OP is getting"* Please quote the part of the answer that explains this. I can't find it.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - be pleased: "A function should never return an error instead of a value."

Comment: Is that "should" or "must", and why is it so? There's a comment on the question which does better. Seems to me you have more grounds on the closing of the question as "too broad" than the deletion of your answer. I don't think people are thinking the question is a request for a review, but it is easy to think that your answer is a critique rather than an answer, with that little quote, indefinite and unexpalined.

Comment: Well, as always, Your Common Sense is exploring the limits of Stack Overflow's rules :) I'm not sure I'm comfortable with the deletion, though. Yes, it should have been worded more nicely, but had someone posted an answer to the OP's specific question, and then added "I think you should completely remodel this thusly:...." and then posted all the design advice from the deleted answer, there's no way it would have been deleted.

Comment: The answer definitely contains valuable advice. I'd suggest rewriting it to tone it down, and then have a moderator undelete it.

Comment: Please note that the mod didn't say the *question* was asking for a code review, they said that your answer was a critique not an answer. If you wanted to avoid that accusation, you could have just given the actual answer (as you say, because one function can return an error, which isn't what the other is expecting) *without* all of the unpleasantness. Burying it in aggression is profoundly unhelpful.

Comment: @Pekka웃 if some design is genuinely awful (in the sense that even for such a subjective term there would be broad agreement by those capable in a language) and you use "completely remodel this", what do you use for something that should be "completely remodelled" but isn't intrinsically awful (say, a particular performance issue in a particular situation)? What does the same carefully-constructed phrase, used in two entirely different situations, mean? Nothing, concretely, or choice of the reader. If something *is* awful, what's wrong with calling it awful?

Comment: @BillWoodger that's sort of my point: the *content* of the answer is ok and it should not have been deleted. It is a "critique" of the code but that's the only reasonable way to respond to the OP's question. I think the wrong decision was made because of Your Common Sense's choice choice of words.

Comment: It's not the part where you help the person out with their code problem, it's the part where you feed them through the wood chipper while doing so.

Answer (score 13):

There are some flaws in your train of thought there. You also conveniently left out the contents of the deleted answer, which are a clear indication of why the answer was removed.

Let's have a look at those bullet points:

1. There's nothing wrong with that being closed as dupe. If a dupe closure is incorrect, you can just re-open it.
2. Which you did. Again, business as usual. However, instead of *"explaining the real cause for the error"*, your answer wasn't constructive. It was rather aggressive:

   > - *"This is because of the awful design."*
   > - *"It spoils all the code involved."*
   > - *"Other methods you wrote are no better."*
   > - *"Refrain from toying with your own classes for a while and learn how to use a ready made class first."*
   > - *"`_error()` -> useless method"*
3. The mod might have come across your answer. If a user flagged it, he probably flagged it for the aggressive language. The assumption that personal feelings are involved is nothing more than that, an assumption.
4. Mods are impartial. They see a report, then act based on the Q/A's merits.

The answer *"Don't write your own, there are some errors"* may be correct, but the way you formed your answer goes against everything the "[Be Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)" policy stands for.

Basically, maybe the problem isn't that the mod's actions aren't justifyable. Maybe it's your own actions that should be reconsidered.

Comment: Against "be nice"? I hope not. No, it is just badly written such that anything good is somewhat hidden, so that it looks at even three glances to be exactly like a critique.

Comment: I wouldn't say calling someone's code "awful" is very nice, or constructive, @BillWoodger. _"Your code is rather flawed"_ seems much better. Other than that, I agree.

Comment: Come on, you based your answer on a mere assumption. But the fact is otherwise: the mod deleted it as not an answer. Please keep to the facts.

Comment: The actual words were that the *design* was awful (admittedly, with no clue as to what design - the language, implementation of the constructor, of OPs code). That aside, if we follow your line, we are no longer able to use "rather flawed" - it either now means "awful" or it means *both* "rather flawed" and "awful" simultaneously, so means nothing. You can't use "be nicer" words to convey the same meaning is the bad words. Although it is done.

Comment: Basically, you don't answer the question asked here, but just trying to lecture me how to behave. It's all right with the lecture, but not disguised as an answer.

Comment: @YourCommonSense again, you made it look like a critique, a critique is not an answer, so deleted as not an answer. If that is just your style, you are going to have to live with it happening. It is unrealistic to expect the general moderation policy to change around your specifics.

Comment: @BillWoodger: It doesn't matter if it's the code, or the design that's called "awful". It's just _not constructive_. YCS: The points I addressed in this answer surely didn't help the mod not to delete that answer. The reason I didn't answer your exact question is that it's based on a misrepresentation of what happened. When that's addressed, the question becomes moot.

Comment: @BillWoodger You all are deliberately trying to move away from the facts, devising whatever reasons different from the actual comment given by the mod.

Comment: @YourCommonSense even though it took me three readings to realise there was an unclear nugget in there, disguised by the other stuff? Up to that point I entirely agreed with the moderator comment. It is unrealistic to expect someone to have to put that much effort into something where a flag has been raised. With a clear explanation there would not have been a problem, I feel. If you want to write like that, you are going to fall foul of "scaling" at times, the amount of time a moderator, with no assumption of domain knowledge, can spend looking at post which "looks like" something else.

Comment: @BillWoodger it's a pity indeed. "It is unrealistic to expect someone to have to put that much effort" says it all. Thank you for being honest at last.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm sure you can really understand the difference between "the" and "your". "The design of something undefined is awful" vs "Your code is awful".

Comment: @YourCommonSense since I have not changed my position, I'll accept what you say as indicating I was honest all along. It is not realistic, if you don't make the effort to be clear, that a moderator should take more effort to think "yes, they may have a point". It looked like critique, critique isn't answer, delete. No aid from you, so not much to complain about.

Comment: @YourCommonSense To be honest I have nothing against the word *awful*, however, you should have explained at least why, otherwise it's not constructive and don't help anyone, neither the OP neither those who read after him, which is the purpose of all SE's sites.

Comment: @Walfrat I agree with you in general but following that rule 99% of answers should be deleted. So it's not actually the [justifiable] reason.

Comment: @YourCommonSense but not all answers get flagged and looked at by a moderator, so no connection there, there is no rule which applies. Flagged *and* looked at by a moderator *and* lacking in explanation. Not just lacking in explanation. I'm not saying that flagging a one-line nothingness which has 100 votes will get any good result either :-), but feel free to try on this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4342263/1927206

Comment: @YourCommonSense To be fair you haven't addressed what several people have raised - that your tone was unnecessarily harsh, and that you can fix the problem easily by rephrasing it and being nicer. Putting aside whether or not the exact deletion reason is correct, why won't you do that?

Answer (score 11):

I'm not getting into the flame-baity premise of the original question title.  I personally think the answer shouldn't have been deleted, but then it is expected that stuff like this happens occasionally when your tone is often more abrasive than strictly necessary.

But to get some perspective. The PHP tag is a mess, and only very few people actually provide what is needed most - sound design advice in response to the thousands of awful code snippets that turn up there every week.

Without those people, the place would be *completely* lost.

The design advice dispensed in his answer is, as far as I can see, pertinent to the question, and exactly what the OP should do. Deleting it is a disservice to both the OP and the community at large.

So how about rewording it to make it sound nicer, and undeleting it.

Something like:

> Your function can return an error instead of the actual value, causing unpredictable behaviour down the line.
>
> A function should never be designed in a way that it could return an error *or* a value.
>
> When starting out with PHP, it may be best to learn how to use a ready made class first and understand the design principles. PDO is arguably the best option: it is a recognized industry standard. It provides everything you built:
>
> ```
>  _query($query) -> $pdo->query($query);
> _get($query) -> $pdo->query($query)->fetch();
> _count($query) -> $pdo->query("SELECT count(*) FROM table")->fetchColumn();
> _select($query) ->  $pdo->query($query)->fetchAll();
> _error() -> redundant method, PDO already throws exceptions
> _secure($value) ->  $pdo->quote($value);
> ```